# Map of water taps to fill bottles

Tags: long-distance, hydration, bottle

Are there any maps of taps where I can fill my water bottles (bidons) on long rides. I live in Scotland, but would be glad to learn of the existence of such resources worldwide.

Comment: Related on [travel.se]: [Where to find public water taps in the Netherlands?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/36473/3221)

Comment: Also living in Scotland I can totally see where you are coming from.  Cafe's don't seem to be as wide spread as in other countries, and in more remote regions, the presence of a shop doesn't necessarily mean its open.

Comment: Yes. I cycled 70 miles to a bike-friendly cafe yesterday. It was closed.

Comment: "Local knowledge" is about the only answer.  I've recently found a fountain behind a cafe, that I didn't know existed for years.

Comment: Personally if in rural Scotland I would be happy filling from a stream direct to the bottle.  There tend to be plenty of streams and the water is generally very pure.

Answer (score 11):

Openstreetmap with the cycle layer certainly shows some. [Here's one](https://www.openstreetmap.org/relation/85421#map=18/44.86840/6.72230&layers=C)
I was [very grateful for](https://www.facebook.com/chris.hodges.96155/videos/vb.1250807942/10216519760767114/?type=2&video_source=user_video_tab) in the French Alps.  OSM is not complete but it's open source so you can improve it (I haven't added any taps, but I have added bike parking).  This is a good approach, as it also shows cafes and shops where you should be able to buy water if there's no tap (flipping between the "standard" and "cycling" layers can show more facilities).

In the UK, the cafes on [Cafe Network](https://www.google.com/maps/d/viewer?mid=1TF8mumGKoA9_kUhQVlaLaEswNBg&ll=54.947235879037095%2C-4.921571910381317&z=5) will almost all be very willing to fill bottles for customers - I normally plan on a cafe stop every few hours and take the opportunity then.  Pubs and coffee shops generally will too. Some chain fast food places won't - they say they can't. This is problematic late at night when nowhere else is open.

A possible fallback in the UK is churchyards - there's generally a tap outside, but no guarantee the pipes aren't lead.

It's possible to query OpenStreetMap for drinking water by modifying the following link to give an appropriate bounding box (the last 4 comma-separated numbers):

https://tools.wmflabs.org/query2map/featurelist.php?key=amenity&value=drinking_water&types=points-areas-infos&BBOX=-2.9914,51.5871,-1.32,50.81

changing `value=drinking_water` to `value=water_point` returns some more (e.g. next to canals, for filling boat tanks).

Of course some are on private land.  I've seen campsites and schools showing all their water points.  But that's fairly obvious from zooming in.  The bigger downside is that many are missing.

Comment: In fact reviewing OSM for this prompted me to add a missing cafe on the same ride I stopped at that spring/fountain/tap

Answer (score 6):

In the USA free tap water is virtually universal, and I was able to fill up my water bottles at any fast food restaurant and convenience store I stopped at, all over the country. A switch on most restaurant soda fountains will dispense plain tap water. I also filled up at local parks and roadside rest areas.

Comment: We've had issues round here with 24 hour McDonald's saying they can't - it's good to hear that's not the case everywhere.

Comment: @ChrisH In that case, "can't" clearly means "won't". The US has two big advantages in this regard: building codes typically require water fountains in areas that are for public use, and free refills in fast food places mean that the dispensers are usually in the customer area, rather than behind the counter.

Comment: @DavidRicherby of course, but after riding all day reasoning with some poor kid on minimum wage in McDonald's is beyond me (and pointless). It's acceptance or getting grumpy.

Comment: @DavidRicherby There are obvious food hygiene issues if a container "of unknown provenance" has to be taken into the "kitchen area" to be filled. AFAIK in the UK pubs (and probably restaurants) are legally required to *serve* plain water to customers, but not required to provide the customers direct uncontrolled access to it.

Comment: @alephzero And these "obvious food hygiene issues" magically disappear if the drinks dispenser is on the public side of the counter. Weird, huh? And, even in the UK, the drinks dispenser isn't in the kitchen; it's in the counter area, where it's handled by staff who've been handling coins all day. Coins are _filthy_.

Comment: @alephzero I looked into this recently.  It's places that serve alcohol (and yes, only required to serve it to customers.  The last cafe I stopped in filled a bottle for me.  the one a couple of hours before that let me go behind the counter to fill my own because the tap was obvious and it was busy.  A few pubs will fill a pint glass rather than a water bottle - but decanting is easy

Answer (score 2):

In the UK, we used to pay tax for public services, now everything has been privatised but we still pay loads of tax. There was a time when most railway stations, bus stations, high streets all had drinking fountains. All of these have been removed, for people to buy plastic water and then throw in landfill. I had thought at one point the access to free clean drinking water was a defining mark of a civilised nation.

On a less pessimistic note, using a map to find water courses, coupled with a handheld water filter, or bottle filter should see you right somewhere like Scotland. They are surprisingly affordable, and some claim to remove 99.99% of bad stuff, seen inline filters for drinking bladders.

Comment: You're absolutely correct, but this doesn't address OP's question, (unless time-travel is the underlying answer.)   I'm going to edit your comment into the answer to make it more useful.

Comment: I am tempted to down vote as its not an answer, but a rant this good gets +1 from me :)